# Why do Perl string operations on Unicode characters add garbage to the string?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, internationalization

Perl:

```
$string =~ s/[áàâã]/a/gi; #This line always prepends an "a"
$string =~ s/[éèêë]/e/gi;
$string =~ s/[úùûü]/u/gi;
```

This regular expression should convert "été" into "ete". Instead, it is converting it to "aetae". In other words, it prepends an "a" to every matched element. Even "à" is converted to "aa".

If I change the first line to this

```
$string =~ s/(á|à|â|ã)/a/gi;
```

it works, but... Now it prepends an `e` to every matched element (like "eetee").

Even though I found a suitable solution, why does it behave that way?

#### Edit 1:

I added "use utf8;", but it did not change the behavior (although it broke my output in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)/[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)).

#### Edit2:

The Stream originates from an Ajax Request, performed by [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). The site it originates from is set to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

I am using [Perl v5.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#2000.E2.80.93present) (`perl -v` returns "This is perl, v5.10.0 built for i586-linux-thread-multi").

Comment: What the site is set to will set the encoding to UTF-8 but it won't tell Perl that. Perl has to explicitly be told that it is reading UTF-8 before it applies character-wise regular expressions rather than bytewise ones. If you are reading the input from STDIN yourself, you need to set binmode as I described. If you are using CGI.pm, you need to either fiddle with the options there or use Encode::decode_utf8 on the input. If you are using some other way of grabbing input, you need to find out about that.

Comment: "use utf8;" only tell that the ***source code*** [is in UTF-8](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html), nothing about the actual operation of the program *itself*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that what is happening is that the [áàâã] part of your regular expression is not actually matching characters, but matching bytes. The UTF-8 encoding of those characters would look literally like this in the regular expression:

```
[\xC3\xA1\xC3\xA0\xC3\xA2\xC3\xA3]
```

And so when the regular expression is fed, for example , 'é' (\xC3\xA9), it looks at it a byte at a time, matches the \xC3, and replaces it with an 'a'. It does this for all of the \xC3 bytes it can find. So, 'été' is turned into 'a\xA9ta\xA9'.

Then the second regular expression, which looks like this:

```
[\xc3\xA9\xC3\xA8\xC3\xAA\xC3\xAB]
```

comes along, and it matches the \xA9 portion, and replaces it with an 'e'. So now, 'a\xA9ta\xA9' is turned into 'aetae'.

When you replace the [áàâã] with (á|à|â|ã), then that matches complete characters correctly on the first pass, but then your second regular expression has the original problem, and \xC3 characters are replaced with 'e' instead.

If this is still happening, even with `use utf8;`, then there may be a bug (or at least a limitation) in the [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) regular expression engine.

Comment: perl -v returns: "This is perl, v5.10.0 built for i586-linux-thread-multi"

Answer (score 8):

The problem is very likely down to not having

```
use utf8;
```

(or its equivalent for whatever coding system you are using) in your program. The weird replacements you have there look like problems with bytewise rather than characterwise regular expression replacement.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, "utf8";
my $string = "été";

$string =~ s/[áàâã]/a/gi; #This line always prepends an "a"
$string =~ s/[éèêë]/e/gi;
$string =~ s/[úùûü]/u/gi;

print "$string\n";
```

prints

```
ete
```

If you are reading input from a file or from standard input, make sure you have the stream set to utf8 or whatever is appropriate for the encoding. For `STDIN` use

```
binmode STDOUT, "utf8";
```

If you are reading from a file, use

```
open my $file, "<:utf8", "file_name"
```

to get the encoding right. If it is not in UTF-8, use `encoding(name)` instead of `utf8`.

Comment: Given that Mike has 'use utf8;' in his source, the Unicode source code will be accepted just fine. That suggests that his input string is not being correctly interpreted. Bear in mind that the utf8 pragma affects program code not source.

Comment: There's no mention in the post of where the input originates from.

Comment: Stream comes from an AJAX Request. See Edit 2

Answer (score 7):

But did you really want to use regexes at all? Perhaps something like [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Unidecode) would be better

```
$ perl -Mutf8 -MText::Unidecode -E 'say unidecode("été")'
ete
```

Comment: Note the importance of the utf8 pragma there. If you have Unicode in your source, you need to tell Perl that.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably due to the fact that you're using UTF8 strings, and it's parsing them as if they're not, or similar.

Instead of using something like `[áàâã]` you should probbaly use something like
`[\xE1-\xE5]`

and probably use `use utf8;` in your code too

Comment: Either one or the other is enough.

Comment: but there's no harm in using both :D

Answer (score 2):

Something tells me it's because it doesn't know how to behave with characters with accent. By looking at your regular expression, everything seems fine. You might want to add:

```
use utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

This could also be a problem with [Unicode Normalisation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/), as certain systems (I'm looking at you, OS X) represent extended Latin1 glyphs as a specific normalised representation that can break regular expressions when you refer to a character specifically instead of using a unicode or hex representation.

Comment: If Mike has "use utf8;" in his program, this problem will be resolved by Perl.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you shouldn't really use regular expressions here. The easiest way to achieve this (although this might be undesirable) would be to convert your input string into US ASCII. The appropriate conversion tables should know that `e` is the closest equivalent to `é`.

Another option would be to use Unicode and normalize your string into NFD. This will break up all accented letters into base letter + diacritic. Then you can just go through your string and remove all combining diacritical characters.