# Normalizing ASCII characters

Tags: perl, ascii, normalization

I need to normalize a string such as "quée" and I can't seem to convert the extended ASCII characters such as é, á, í, etc into roman/english versions. I've tried several different methods but nothing works so far. There is a fair amount of material on this general subject but I can't seem to find a working answer to this problem.

Here's my code:

```
#transliteration solution (works great with standard chars but doesn't find the 
#special ones) - I've tried looking for both \x{130} and é with the same result.
$mystring =~ tr/\\x{130}/e/;

#converting into array, then iterating through and replacing the specific char
#( same result as the above solution )
my @breakdown = split( "",$mystring );

foreach ( @breakdown ) {
    if ( $_ eq "\x{130}" ) {
        $_ = "e";
        print "\nArray Output: @breakdown\n";
    }
    $lowercase = join( "",@breakdown );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) This [article](http://ahinea.com/en/tech/accented-translate.html) should provide a fairly good (if complicated) way.

It provides a solution to converting all accented Unicode characters into the base character + accent; once that is done you can simply remove the accent characters separately.

---

2) Another option is CPAN: [`Text::Unaccent::PurePerl`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Unaccent::PurePerl) (An improved Pure Perl version of `Text::Unaccent`)

---

3) Also, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572516/119280) proposes `Text::Unidecode`:

> ```
> $ perl -Mutf8 -MText::Unidecode -E 'say unidecode("été")'
>   ete
> ```

Answer (score 7):

The reason your original code doesn't work is that `\x{130}` is not é.  It's  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE (U+0130 or İ)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/130/index.htm).  You meant `\x{E9}` or just `\xE9` (the braces are optional for two-digit numbers), [LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (U+00E9)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm).

Also, you have an extra backslash in your `tr`; it should look like `tr/\xE9/e/`.

With those changes, your code will work, although I'd still recommend using one of the modules on CPAN for this sort of thing.  I prefer [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Unidecode) for this myself, as it handles much more than just accented characters.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I implemented your changes and it works now. I am in fact using a module in the delivered version since it seems to be the most elegant way, though it's good to know I wasn't too far off.

Answer (score 3):

After working and re-working, here's what I have now. It's doing everything I want except I would like to keep spaces in the middle of input strings to differentiate between words.

```
open FILE, "funnywords.txt";

# Iterate through funnywords.txt
while ( <FILE> ) {
    chomp;

    # Show initial text from file
    print "In: '$_' -> ";

    my $inputString = $_;

    # $inputString is scoped within a for each loop which dissects
    # unicode characters ( example: "é" splits into "e" and "´" )
    # and throws away accent marks. Also replaces all
    # non-alphanumeric characters with spaces and removes
    # extraneous periods and spaces.
    for ( $inputString ) {
        $inputString = NFD( $inputString ); # decompose/dissect
        s/^\s//; s/\s$//;                   # strip begin/end spaces
        s/\pM//g;                           # strip odd pieces
        s/\W+//g;                           # strip non-word chars
    }

    # Convert to lowercase 
    my $outputString = "\L$inputString";

    # Output final result
    print "$outputString\n";
}
```

Not entirely sure why it's coloring some of the regex and comments red...

Here are a few examples of lines from "funnywords.txt":

quée

22.

?éÉíóñúÑ¿¡

[ .this? ]

aquí, aLLí

Answer (score 2):

For your second question about getting rid of any remaining symbols but keeping letters and numbers change your last regex from `s/\W+//g` to `s/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+//g`.  Since you've already normalized the rest of the input, using that regex will remove anything that is not a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or whitespace.  Using the [] and a ^ at the beginning will indicate that you want to look for everything that is NOT in the rest of the bracket.